# Graphite: group by node fragment

Tags: graphite, grafana

If I have metrics named:

```
statsite.gauges.a-ABC-1.thing
statsite.gauges.a-ABC-2.thing
statsite.gauges.a-CBA-1.thing
```

Is it possible to group these metrics by a particular fragment, for instance:

```
statsite.gauges.a-{groupByThisPart}-*.thing
```

So that I can feed them into another function such as sumSeries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible by using aliasSub to convert the '-' into '.', as follows, apply:

```
aliasByNode(seriesName, 2)
```

which outputs 'a-CBA-1'. Then apply:

```
aliasSub(seriesName, \d{4})-(\d{4})-(\w{5}, \1.\2.\3)
```

which outputs 'a.CBA.1'.

Then you can use groupByNode to sum all the parts for the 2nd fragment.

```
groupByNode(seriesName, 1, sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Every series matched by the expression you use will be rendered separately. So if you do:

```
statsite.gauges.a-*-*.thing
```

All series matching that pattern will be displayed. There are some functions like [sumSeriesWithWildcards](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.sumSeriesWithWildcards) that your can use to perform the aggregation only with respect to a certain position, but positions are delimited by dots, so I don't think you can do what you want with Graphite.

I believe the best option is to rename your metrics so you separate every part you'd like to group by by dots.